# how to Retrieve in google app engine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google App Engine in my project, using Entity I am storing and retrieving information, but my problem is when ever I am searching for the information with the special character it is not working(I am using emailid for search), Can any one give the solution for it?(ID/Name, email, userName - all will have same information)

for example I am search the emailid `szitás93@example.com` even entity key is

`Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("DatastoreInformation", email);
System.out.println("The value of key going to search "+k);`

output
`The value of key going to search DatastoreInformation("szitás93@example.com")
Exception occured
entity info in the delete function null
user didn't found`

In datastore

`(Key)ahFsb2dpbndpdGhnb29nZWxpZHIlCxIIQ29udGFjdHMiF3N6aXTDg8KhczkzQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tDA
(Write Ops)10
(ID/Name)szitás93@example.com
(email)szitás93@example.com
(name)Szitás Szandra
(password)Szandra93!_
(userName)szitás93@example.com`

but the information is not retrieving

My code

```
public String deleteUser(String email){ 
   Entity user = checkUserAvailability(email);  

   if(user != null) { 
       Key userKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DatastoreInformation", email); 
       entityStore.delete(userKey); 
       System.out.println("user deleted successfully"); 

       return "Success"; 
   } else{ 
      System.out.println("user didn't found"); return "Failure"; } 
   }

   public Entity checkUserAvailability(String email) { 
        Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("DatastoreInformation", email); 
        System.out.println("The value of key going to search "+k); 
      try { 
         Entity entityAvailable = entityStore.get(k);
        return entityAvailable;
     } catch (EntityNotFoundException excep) { 
         System.out.println("Exception occured");
     }
     return null;
}
```

I am sorry for alignment or any mistake in the question.

Comment: can you please share your code how you search

Comment: @MichaelMeyer This what I did in code, `szitás93@example.com` for this input the datastore is responding with null, even I tried with query fetch